# how to pass long int from php to mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, long-integer

I am dealing with long ints.

I formed a query array in php, like the following:

```
$find_count = array("key"=>$keyword, "type"=>$type, "fromTime"=>array('$gt'=> $fromTimeEpoch, "\$lte" => $toTimeEpoch));

$cursor_count = $coll_count->find($find_count, $projection_count);//Query mongodb. $coll_count is a MongoDB collection.
```

Here $fromTimeEpoch and $toTimeEpoch are LONG variables.

When i echo $find_count, then $fromTimeEpoch and $toTimeEpoch are printed fine (something like 1372617000000)

However these queries are not reaching correctly to mongo server.
What mongo server receives as the values of $fromTimeEpoch and $toTimeEpoch are negative ints (something like -1858934720).

So the question is why are these LONGs converting to negative ?

What is the correct way to pass long variables in php ?

NOTE: in my mongo database, "fromTime" field is of type LONG (and not STRING).

Comment: I can't quite remember why they are negative, it is always something I forget but I do know it is technically correct though (it is that much past the 32bit limit) it isn't much use to you. If you use either the http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongoint64.php or the runtime var (as is the recommended approach most of the time) http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.configuration.php#ini.mongo.native-long

Comment: @Sammaye: Using ini_set('mongo.native_long', 1) worked ! Gosh.. i wasted 1 hour for this. Thanks a ton !

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with time and searching by time, you should be using MongoDate()

```
$start = new MongoDate(strtotime("2010-01-15 00:00:00"));
$end = new MongoDate(strtotime("2010-01-30 00:00:00"));

// find dates between 1/15/2010 and 1/30/2010
$collection->find(array("ts" => array('$gt' => $start, '$lte' => $end)));
```